# sorting a list manually on python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to sort a list of integers in Python without using the `sort()` function.

In my code there's an error when the program tries deleting the lowest value from the unordered list.

I have already rewritten the code and tried different things like `.remove()` rather than delete but just can't figure out how to do it.

```
unordered = [18 ,13 ,44 ,12,19 ,27,2,31]
print(unordered)
ordered = []
lowest = unordered[0]
indexOfLowest = 0

while len(unordered) > 0:
    for number in unordered:
        if number < lowest:
            lowest = number
            indexOfLowest = unordered.index(lowest)
    del unordered[indexOfLowest]
    ordered.append(lowest)
print(ordered)
```

Comment: If you are sorting you shouldn't need to remove anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bring some of your initialization into the loop like:

#### Code:

```
unordered = [18, 13, 44, 12, 19, 27, 2, 31]
print(unordered)
ordered = []

while unordered:
    lowest = unordered[0]
    index_of_lowest = 0
    for i, number in enumerate(unordered):
        if number < lowest:
            lowest = number
            index_of_lowest = i
    del unordered[index_of_lowest]
    ordered.append(lowest)
print(ordered)
```

#### Results:

```
[18, 13, 44, 12, 19, 27, 2, 31]
[2, 12, 13, 18, 19, 27, 31, 44]
```

Comment: Thank you.If you don't mind could you give some explanation to why I have to bring it to the loop.

Comment: `unordered` is changing, so you have to reset the values each time.